# Running DiskWarrior from Boot Recovery Terminal for encrypted disks does not work

Tags: recovery

The instructions that come with Disk Warrior state you should boot in Recovery Mode by:

- Holding <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
- Open Terminal
- Run command `/Volumes/DW/go`

If you run this command you get an error saying that the directory cannot be found.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the instructions for are somewhat lacking and there are some missed steps and incorrect ones. After some trial and error here's how I got it running.

**Drive is not encrypted**

You can either run the USB as a bootable drive by holding Alt on boot. Or if you really need to run it from the boot recovery terminal you can skip steps 5-7

**If drive is encrypted using FileVault 2**

1. Install DiskWarrior on a working Mac & enter key
2. Use the Bootable disk wizard to create a bootable USB
3. Rename the USB drive to DW & eject
4. Insert USB into mac that needs to be repaired and power up mac while holding Apple + R
5. Open Disk Utility
6. Select drive and then select 'Unlock' & enter password to unlock
7. Close Disk Utility
8. Open Terminal
9. Run command: `/Volumes/DW/Applications/DiskWarrior.app/Contents/MacOS/DiskWarrior`

DiskWarrior should now start and you can repair your drive.